# What is a higher reliability protocol than TCP?

Tags: tcp, network-programming, protocols, reliability

I know that TCP has a 16-bit checksum, to catch errors in transmission. So what TCP outputs on the other end is theoretically reliable... to a point.

This article suggests that TCP is not as reliable as one might hope if they are after "high reliability":
http://iang.org/ssl/reliable_connections_are_not.html#ref_6

**Are there readily available protocols, or even transport libraries (C/C++ preferred), that are more reliable than TCP?** Speed of moderate concern too.

I would imagine a transport library would effectively be a reimplementation of most of the parts of TCP.

It is a shame that TCP isn't more flexible to allow a tradeoff for more reliability at the cost of throughput/latency/speed. You could get a lot more reliability if you even made the checksum 32-bit instead of 16-bit. And again if you chose to make it 64-bit.
There seems to be a very big cost to adding your own reliable transport layer on top of TCP: for starters, the hardware acceleration support for processing TCP won't suffice, and you'll need to provide some of your CPU time to process this layer. Additionally, it is a lot of extra complexity and code to implement such a thing, which could have been all avoided if the TCP checksum was larger or selectable.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please help me improve my questions in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TLS](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt)

Widely deployed, well understood, plenty of libraries available in all commonly used languages.

If by 'reliability' you understand a better chance to detect stream alteration (bad hardware or malicious interference) then cryptographic HMAC is *the* way to go. And TLS is pretty much the industry standard.

Comment: Ah thanks, I'm not even interested in cryptography or malicious attackers (the user has direct physical control of the channel), so I didn't even consider that as a solution. I was thinking the unreliability would be bit flips from channel interference or whatever. I'll have a quick read of it and let you know if it's what I'm after. :)

Comment: This is the feature that I'm after: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Data_integrity
Seems to be the appropriate protocol, even though it carries a lot of extra features I'm not interested in. It is standard though. Thanks. :)